# Record video from JFrame

Tags: java, video, jframe

I've a JFrame application that can produce long running-time output. I wonder if I can record that and produce a video or frames/images with a high frame rate to convert them to video later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce an image of the content of the `JFrame` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(),
            frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    frame.paint(image.getGraphics());
    File outputfile = new File("C:/Temp/frame.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
}
```

Then used any of the numerous software converter available to build a video from it.